# Toggling php generated div elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am fetching data from using mysql to generate div tags in a sort of hierarchy structure. There are div tags inside div tags which are inside div tags. This is created using nested while loops. The output is like this where the ids are uniquely made through php:

```
<div class="holder">
    <label class="toggle" id=$courseCategory>Category 1</label>
    <div class="content" id=$courseCategory>
        <label class="toggle" id=$courseTopic>Topic 1</label>
        <div class="content" id=$courseTopic>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="toggle" id=$courseCategpry>Category 2</label>
</div>
```

And that is the basic structure of the generated content.

The PHP that is creating the structure is this:

```
<?php 
include "connect.php";

global $con;

$qryCat=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT CourseCategory FROM tblCourse");


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qryCat, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $courseCat = $row['CourseCategory'];
    //print $courseCat 

    echo "<label  class ='toggle' id='".$courseCat."'>".$courseCat."</label>";
    echo "<div  class ='content' style = 'display:none;' id='div".$courseCat."'>";

    $qryTop=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT CourseTopic FROM tblCourse WHERE CourseCategory = '$courseCat'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qryTop, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $courseTop = $row['CourseTopic'];
        //print $courseTop;
        echo "<label class ='toggle' id='".$courseTop."'>".$courseTop."</label><br/>";
        echo "<div class ='content' style = 'display:none;' id='div".$courseTop."'>";

        $qryLevel=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT CourseLevel FROM tblCourse WHERE CourseCategory = '$courseCat' AND CourseTopic = '$courseTop'");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qryLevel, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $courseLevel = $row['CourseLevel'];
            //print $courseLevel;
            echo "<label class ='toggle' id='".$courseTop.$courseLevel."'>".$courseLevel."</label><br/>";
            echo "<div class ='content' style = 'display:none;' id='div'".$courseTop.$courseLevel."'>";

            $qryCourse=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT CourseCode, CourseName FROM tblCourse WHERE CourseCategory = '$courseCat' AND CourseTopic = '$courseTop' AND CourseLevel = '$courseLevel'");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qryCourse, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $courseCode =$row['CourseCode'];
                $courseName = $row['CourseName'];
                //print $courseName;
                echo "<label id='".$courseCode."'>".$courseName."</label><br/>";
                echo "<div id='div".$courseCode."'></div>";
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</div><br/>";
}
?>
```

I want to use jQuery to toggle each section like a menu. So when I press Category 1, All the topics under Category 1 are show, which I can then click on the topics to show the next level of the menu.

I have tried a couple of different things in trying to get this to work. The below code works for the first level. I can toggle the categories, however nothing happens when clicking on the topics that are shown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".content").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I have also tried this code which allows the entire "tree" to expand, however it toggles all siblings.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".content").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Both have aspects that I want for the final result but I can't figure out how to navigate the tree in order to do what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: After looking through the PHP to see if that was the issue I still can't get it working. I have added the PHP to see if someone with sharper eyes can see if that is the problem.

Comment: your code works for me, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/opoocgrw/). Though there are some alignment correction required.

Comment: Code is working at my end.Check this http://jsfiddle.net/23yxj3ny/

Comment: It's working like a charm.. I've updated Bhushan Kawadkar's [link](http://jsfiddle.net/opoocgrw/7/)

Comment: It looks like with the hard coded structure it is working fine, so I guess that means it is a problem with the way I am generating the div tags in the php, rather than a problem with the jQuery. I will change that and see what happens. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it? Is this you are looking or

1. you are looking like "ACCORDION MENU"?
2. Your Code is working fine. The Problem may be there is no content in Category 2.

Script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".content").toggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
label + .content{
    display:none;
}
label + .open{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <label class="toggle" id=$courseCategory>Category 1</label>
    <div class="content open" id=$courseCategory>
        <label class="toggle" id=$courseTopic>Topic 1</label>
        <div class="content" id=$courseTopic>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <label class="toggle" id=$courseCategpry>Category 2</label>
    <div class="content" id=$courseCategory>
        <label class="toggle" id=$courseTopic>Topic 2</label>
        <div class="content" id=$courseTopic>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <label class="toggle" id=$courseCategpry>Category 3</label>
    <div class="content" id=$courseCategory>
        <label class="toggle" id=$courseTopic>Topic 3</label>
        <div class="content" id=$courseTopic>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
</div>
```

Attempt #2 In php

```
<div class="holder">
    <?php 
        $count=0;
        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){ 
        $count=$count+1;
    ?>
    <label class="toggle" id=$courseCategory>Category <?php echo $count; ?></label>
    <div class="content open" id=$courseCategory>
        <label class="toggle" id=$courseTopic>Topic <?php echo $count; ?></label>
        <div class="content" id=$courseTopic>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like with the hard coded structure it is working fine, so I guess that means it is a problem with the way I am generating the div tags in the php, rather than a problem with the jQuery. I will change that and see what happens. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your are binding click event that are being generated dynamically. So may be the click function is not binded with elements at that moment.

Check below link
 http://jsfiddle.net/23yxj3ny/1/

```
$(".holder").on('click','.toggle',function() {
      $(this).siblings(".content").toggle("slow");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the problem was with the PHP. I guess when the 
 was being echo'd after the  it was changing the structure of the . After removing the 
 it works perfect!